# Elasticsearch indices folder should be renamed and append with currentdate

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

My requirement is when the logstash giving input to the elasticsearch it starts creating indices in the data directory currently the indices folder name is like this "**8Vrmw6l3ToWu32FQ7nuWUw**" my requirement is this name should be a created date like "**Logstash-YYYY.MM.dd**" there is any way or workaround is there to acheive this, am using ELK setup in my local machine logstash-5.5.0 kibana-5.5.0 elasticsearch-5.5.0 and my logstash.conf file is look like

Thanks in advance,
Suganth A.

Answer (score 1):

No. The behavior was actually changed to this new format to avoid any problems with special characters or length limits in index names, which could cause issues on some file systems.

Why would you want to do that? Neither deletes nor snapshots (backups) should be done directly on the filesystem.

Comment: Thansk Xeraa, If it the folder named as a date while taking backup it will be helpfull for me thats why i thouyght to do this, Good reply, Thanks again.

Comment: Use the [snapshot and restore API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) for that. It's incremental and safe to use while Elasticsearch is running. If this answered your question, please mark it accordingly.